# Heap out of memory Error in ionic command- npm run build --aot

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, ionic3

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

The command I usually use is `npm run build --aot`

After searching the web, I used the below command, but the result is the same.

`npm run build --aot node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts`

My project is big, and there was no error since I added two more pages. If I remove these pages am I able to make a build?

My [Ionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)) information is below:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\saurabh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

This issue is happening on this project only.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal console:

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096`

If using Windows:

`set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096`

Run the above command and then run `ionic build --prod`.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the below command:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same error.

Try this:

```
npm run build --aot --minifyjs --minifycss
```

If it doesn't help,

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 /usr/local/bin/ionic npm run build --prod --release
```

Comment: its not for android its for web, tried both, this is what i tried, still the same error - `npm run build --aot node --max-old-space-size=8096 ./node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts`

Comment: if i try your 2nd command, i am getting error `Cannot find module 'D:\usr\local\bin\ionic'`  , where is it referring too ?